# Get value of an html element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My code:

```
<div id="all">
   <ul class="gnr">

     <li><a class="lnk" href="#" title="Link1">Link1</a></li>
     <li><a class="lnk" href="#" title="Link2">Link2</a></li>
     <li><a class="lnk" href="#" title="Link3">Link3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

All links are the "lnk" class and I want to do is that when you click on any of them the value of the "title" attribute is stored in a variable and send it using ajax function of jQuery to a php document.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is almost javascript/jQuery 101 I'm gonna attempt to answer this without doing it for you.

Here are a couple things you're gonna need.

1. [Learn about jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
2. [Bind a click event to a jQuery object](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
3. [`title` is an attribute of what was clicked](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)
4. [Then you want ajax to a php page](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: i wish more people would answer questions in this way